# Android ListView - how to predict how many row can be displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity

Since Android has different size of layout, the number of rows can be shown in the `ListView` is therefore variable, ideally, we need to perform API call like..

```
http://www.example.com/get_product?count=N&..
```

Where `N` = number of rows can be displayed in a given  `ListView` + 10 items buffer for offscreen scrolling effect.

What would be best method to define the value of `N` in the app?

Comment: If your rows have a fixed height, then divide the ListView's height by the row height. Otherwise you will have to calculate each row height individually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list) //R.id.list will be your listview id in the layout    
int n = Double.intValue(list.getHeight()/list.getChildAt(1).getHeight())
```

If it doesn't work because it need to first create the list to get a child, and you have the dp height of the listItem (could be if you use a custom layout), you could use

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list) //R.id.list will be your listview id in the layout    
Resources r = getResources();
int px = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, !!!YOUR LISTITEM HEIGHT IN DP!!!, r.getDisplayMetrics())); //Convert DP to actual size in pixels (rounded)
int n = Double.intValue(list.getHeight()/px)
```

Answer (score 0):

> set [onScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) to listview using method listView.setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener).
>    @param visibleItemCount of
>   method onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int
>   visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) is what you are looking for .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom adapter like BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter, then `getCount()` will give you the nos of View to be inflated in the ListView.

**That will give you the Number of Rows**

`getCount()` is the called **before** the `getView()` method, cause `getCount()` only tells how many Views to inflated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getListView().getChildCount()` to get the number of visible items. Though this can only be called after your ListView is displayed. So I am not sure if you will get this on the first attempt when you try to get the number of items.